# Executing a query on a remote sqlite database via JCIFS

Tags: android, sqlite, samba, jcifs

For an Android project of mine I have to access an SQLite Database somewhere on a shared Windows Workgroup. Other (desktop) applications also make use of this database.
Now I managed to access this network using the JCIFS-Library, but I can't find out how (if at all possible) I can execute a query on the database.
My current solution is to copy the database to my app, execute the desired queries, and then replace the file on the shared location with my manipulated version. This works well enough for queries where I only have to look something up, but adding, deleting or changing rows would be near impossible to properly synchronize.
 Is there any way to accomplish this? And if so, what direction should I look in?